# Entity Framework 6 update record SaveChanges does nothing

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using the following code in an ASP.NET MVC project to update a record (using a JSON call from AngularJS code, but that shouldn't make a difference, right?):

```
public JsonResult UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    Person pers = db.People.Single(p => p.BusinessEntityID == person.BusinessEntityID);
    pers.FirstName = person.FirstName;
    pers.MiddleName = person.MiddleName;
    pers.LastName = person.LastName;
    pers.Suffix = person.Suffix;
    pers.Title = person.Title;
    pers.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    db.Entry(pers).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { status = "Person successfully saved." });
}
```

When I step through the code, everything looks great for the properties for both the "pers" object and the "person" object. But when I get to the "db.SaveChange()" line, the code just does nothing. I get no error, but I also never get beyond it. It's as if the code just ends.

I've also tried this code that I found, but again, the SaveChanges line does nothing.

```
public JsonResult UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    db.People.Attach(person);
    db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { status = "Person successfully saved." });
}
```

Any idea what's happening here? It seems from all the articles I've found all over the place that this should work, yet it doesn't. Again: no errors. The code just stops. I never get to the "return Json" line at all.

Comment: What is db? Could you show how you instantiate it?

Comment: What do you mean by do nothing? Does it throw an Exception and you are not catching it but there is no side affect in the DB? Does it execute and go to the next line? Does it hang indefinitely (ie. deadlock)? To rule out the Exception attach your debugger OR put a try/catch around the call to `SaveChanges` and see if you step into the catch (or return a different result and log the Exception).